# Removing tax block from sales_order_view cause subtotal showing without tax

Tags: magento2, tax, tax-calculation

I have removed tax block from all sales page by adding following code.

layout file is `Magento_Sales\layout\default.xml`

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="tax" remove="true"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

Actual Results[image]

---

Expected Result[image]

How can I make subtotal shows including tax but tax line is removed by `<referenceBlock name="tax" remove="true"/>` ?

Answer (score 0):

**Please Change Tax Setting**

Your Product price must be shown as including tax

> Go to Store > configuration > sales > tax > tax classes > Price
> display setting > Display product price in catalog set to Including
> Tax.